# HTML Website, Email issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, email

Hi I need some code to send e-mail directly with javascript, without load the information on a outlook server, or any other email server. 
I am using HTML as its a static website. Is there any way to achieve this or do I have to move to asp.net just to get the system.mail library.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options, unfortunately no one fits perfectly your definition

- you can use a third party email form system. You basically set up a contact form (fields, tos, ccs...) that is than loaded to your page.
- You call a server-side method that is managing your request (so you should go for ASP.NET or any other server side language)
- You have a WebService way to contact your mail server and submit email requests, than you'll just need an ajax call to perform the operation
- Call the user mail client (i.e Outlook, Thunderbird)

Answer (score 2):

No, in javascript all you can do is to open the mail client (if any).

To send a mail directly you must use a server side language

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't have server side access to a mail server, and if it's about sending a form / feedback, on plain html you can use a 3rd party email form system. There are numerous companies who offer free email forms, you submit the html form to their server, and they send the form to the address you wish.

For example, you can try this one: http://www.emailmeform.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in client side without calling the user mail client (i.e Outlook, Thunderbird). You can use asp.net or PHP for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Email functionality is a server-side function. So, yes, you will need to revert to a server-side technology like asp.net.

How about using ajax controls? that way you can give the impression of "client-side" emailing without page flicker.